# How to add Parse keys in the Strings.Xml file?

Tags: android, parse-platform

In the past I would do something similar to `Parse.initialize(this, Keys.APP_ID, Keys.CLIENT_KEY)` in a class that extends Application but recently they changed what they how you should setup the project to `Parse.initialize(this)` and I would put the actual String in a meta-data tag in the manifest.  I was wondering if there was a benefit to this over the old way because with this new way I cant upload my project to github and simply put Keys file in the gitignore.

Comment: Could an alternative be to place your key in a separate `strings.xml`, (`key_strings.xml`) and git ignore that file? Android doesn't care what you name the xml file as long as you have the `<string>` tag correct. Then in the manifest you should be able to do `@string/parse_key`. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: thanks, ill do that. I cant believe I didnt think of it. Still I dont get why parse keeps changing how they do things.

Comment: Is the issue solved?